# Can I download a single file in Multiple folder using Webdriver java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using this code to download. my goal is to download this file in 4 different locations. Right now the file is going to default Downloads folder.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/Browser_Driver/chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.manage().window().maximize();

 driver.get("https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/");
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("download .csv file")).click();
```

Comment: Nope. Only thing that you can try is AutoIT and Robot class (not suggested)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do it, you'll have to make a hack of some sort. 
This helped me. https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your Question:

You can easily download the same file (e.g. IEDriverServer_Win32_3.3.0.zip) by any name of your choice (e.g. D_Dev.zip) and at any (multiple) location you wish. For that you have to take help of AutoIT. You need to install the SciTE editor. Write a simple script as follows:

```
Example()

Func Example()
    Local $sFilePath1 = "D:\Downloads\D_Debanjan.zip"
    Local $sFilePath2 = "E:\Downloads\E_Debanjan.zip"
    Local $hDownload = InetGet("http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.3/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.3.0.zip", $sFilePath1, $INET_FORCERELOAD)
    Local $hDownload = InetGet("http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.3/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.3.0.zip", $sFilePath2, $INET_FORCERELOAD)

EndFunc
```

This simple script downloads the same "IEDriverServer.exe" in 2 different zipped files by the name "D_Debanjan.zip" & "E_Debanjan.zip", where "D_Debanjan.zip" is saved in "D:\Downloads\" & "E_Debanjan.zip" is saved in "E:\Downloads\" directories.

Let me know if this answers your Question.